# wxPython: Right-align the numbers in a wx.SpinCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, alignment, spinner

A primary reason to use `wx.SpinCtrl` is to restrict the user to input integers, therefore I think that the text inside it would look better if right-aligned.

Is there a way to do this in wxPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a control you can use. It's called FloatSpin, which is in the agw sub-library. If you don't already have it, download the wxPython demo and check it out!

- Mike

Comment: Is it already in the default wxPython download? Or do I need the wxPython demo download? When I install the demo, can I simply do an `import wx.lib.agw as agw`?

Comment: +1 Totally missed that(and I double-checked the demo before..). You don't need the demo, floatSpin is part of wxPython, but It is certainly very handy -plenty of code in there for the floatSpin to show the various features as well as all the other available widgets.

Comment: I just recommended the demo since it showed how to use the widget.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out the demos just for a taste of what all the libraries inside wx can offer.

Comment: Thanks everyone :) I'll dive into `wx.lib.agw.FloatSpin` then.